# ASM 8086 : How is coding with multiple code segments different from coding with one code segment?

Tags: assembly, executable, x86-16

I am a high school student, and this year I started learning assembly.

I am currently making a Pacman clone as my final project.
The only issue that I'm having is that my code is big, and the *.exe file is almost at 64KB.

So my question is, if I move to model medium, what do I need to do to make my code work with the extra code segment?

I think that I need to use `Icall` instead of `call`, and update the procedures since now every time that I call them both the segment and ip get pushed, but is there anything else that I need to do?

Comment: The exact effort required depends on the assembler of choice (I assume you are programming for DOS). As you noted, calls eventually need to be far (including `retf`). I can't think of anything else off the top of my head. If the size of the executable exceeds 640KiB (or less) you may need to use [overlays](http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/vcm.html).

Comment: @MargaretBloom So all I need to do is update the procedures (calls, rets, parameters address in stack etc) and that's it?  Do I need to use overlays only when the executable file is larger than 640KB?

Comment: It's been a long time since the last time I programmed with multiple code segments, better wait for more informed people :) But I'm tempted to answer: yes

Comment: You don't need anywhere near 64K of code to write a Pacman clone in assembly. Your .EXE is probably getting near 64K in size because of data like buffers, the map, and bitmaps. Make sure you're using the small memory model, with separate code and data segments, and have your linker generate a link map to see how big each segment is.

Comment: I agree with Ross. It's *very* unlikely that you need to have more than 64K bytes of code. You can probably get away with the small model, where there is one code segment of 64K bytes max and one data/stack segment of 64K bytes max. If that isn't enough, then the most likely choice would be the compact model, which has 1 code segment and multiple data segments. I doubt you will need the medium model, with its multiple code segments. If you have more than 64K bytes of assembly code, you are overusing macros, resulting in bloated inlined code. Change them to procedures.

Answer (score 3):

If you work in a model with more than one code segment, every code pointer becomes a 32 bit pointer. That means:

- instead of `call` and `ret`, you need to use `call far` and `ret far` (this is something the assembler might do for you)
- `call far` pushes a four byte return address on the stack, so you need to adjust the offsets for fetching arguments
- function pointers need to be 32 bit as they also need to contain the code segment

For your purpose, it might be enough to just use the *small* model, that is, one segment for code and one for data and stack. This way, your executable can be up to 128 kB in size. The small model is very similar to the tiny model in that you can mostly ignore segmentation unless you need to read/write data from the text segment.

Answer (score 1):

For medium model (multiple code segments, one data segment), jumps within a code segment will be small (16 bit offset), jumps between code segments will be far (32 bit segment:offset). For functions that are only called within the same code segment, they can be declared as near and a near call (16 bit offset) will be used. Example code for Masm 6.x, the call and return for *nearfun* uses near call and return, the call and return for *farfun* uses far call and return.

```
        .286
        .model  medium
        .stack  1024

        .code   one                     ;code segment named "one"
main    proc    far
        call    nearfun                 ;call near function
        call    farfun                  ;call far  function
        mov     ax,04c00h               ;exit to dos
        int     21h
main    endp

nearfun proc    near
        mov     ax,1
        ret
nearfun endp

        .code   two                     ;code segment named "two"
farfun  proc    far
        mov     ax,2
        ret
farfun  endp

        end     main
```

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but  what does the ".code text1/2" line does? Does it specifie which code segment is the procedure on?

Comment: Yes, @Jordan. `.CODE` means that this is a section that will store code, and the identifier following it is the name of that section. As rcgldr says, when you use the medium model, you have one data segment (`.data`) and multiple code (`.code`) segments, so you need a way to distinguish those code segments. Most assemblers let you assign labels of your choice to them.

Comment: @JordanErikson - I changed the example code to use the names `one` and `two`. For assembly code, the programmer can use just about anything for the names.  I think the C compiler uses names like `x_text`.

Comment: @rcgldr your code display this error in emu8086 `duplicate declaration of: CODE` and in GUI TURBO `Forward reference needs override`.

Comment: @Doda - the code is meant for Masm (ml.exe) 6.xx as noted in the answer. I don't know how this would be done with other assemblers, but my guess is to use the older Masm 5.xx type replacing the doc directives like `.code` with `segment` and `ends` directives.